# itemRenderer in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

how can I write the following code in ActionScript?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid  id="dg" dataProvider="{xc}" width="100%">
             <mx:groupedColumns>
               <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  headerText="Type" dataField="rgroup1">
                 <mx:itemRenderer>
                   <mx:Component>
                     <mx:LinkButton label={data.rgroup1}" click="outerDocument.expandCollaps(event)" textDecoration="{data.expand}"/>
                   </mx:Component>
                 </mx:itemRenderer>
               </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn >
            </mx:groupedColumns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid >
```

Comment: Check here http://techrays.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/dynamically-creating-a-column-grouped-advanceddatagrid/ for a blog post with code

Comment: What did you try and why did you have problems?  Do you want to know how to re-create the itemRenderer?  Or the DataGrid also?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare renderer component's absolute path like:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid  id="dg" dataProvider="{xc}" width="100%">
         <mx:groupedColumns>
           <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  headerText="Type" dataField="rgroup1" itemRenderer="com.xyz.view.renderers.RendererComponent">
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn >
        </mx:groupedColumns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid >
```

In short, make Pure AS3 RendererComponent and declare inline to MX declaration.